# UIView - Center alignment all the contents of UIView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, rotation, alignment

How to center alignment all the contents of view. When i am rotating iPad contents are not align center it self how to resolve this problem??

Thanks!!!

Comment: do you use nib files or do you add it programmatically?

Comment: I am using nib file for this. I know there is Alignment property for this but by setting this I am still facing same problem after rotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provide an implementation of the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method and center all subviews.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    for(UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
        subview.center = self.view.center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change programmatic-ally the contents' frame  for both Landscape and portrait modes.
You can try this as:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        // set contents' frame for landscape
    }

    else {
        // set contents' frame for portrait

    }

    return YES;
}
```